# Rails pagination by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, pagination

I'm looking to implement pagination based on a date.

I am using a named_scope to pull a note for today but I'd like to add functionality to be able to have a previous link that will show a note for yesterday.

If I happened to be on the page for yesterday I'd also like to be able to have a link that will show the day before yesterday and a link that will go forward one day, back to today, and so on...

I'm wondering if there are any helpers or plugins that would achieve this simply or if someone could point me in the right direction (I'm struggling to know what to even search for).

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not exactly pagination 'cause eventually you could have more than n (where n = per_page records) records count for a given date, I think you should write a `previous_day` and `next_day` helper using the `yesterday` and `tomorrow` methods, something like:

```
def previous_day_for(date)
  link_to "previous", your_filter_path(:date => date.yesterday.to_s(:db))
end

def next_day_for(date)
  link_to "next", your_filter_path(:date => date.tomorrow.to_s(:db))
end
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I think the point is that date-based pagination would use a date, and abandon the entire concept of a per-page value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the will_paginate plugin and setting the page size to 1?  If you sort the data by date, then you could have your pagination working with 1,2,3.  The links can then be customized, or you could create your own helpers that change links using the `page_link` function

will_paginate:  http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

page_link documentation:  http://gitrdoc.com/rdoc/mislav/will_paginate/b3b0f593ea9b1da13a64bc825dfe17b6bbc2828b/classes/WillPaginate/LinkRenderer.html#M000159

I hope this helps!